# How do I search in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, search

I'm very new to AWS and I recently learnt about S3 and Kendra Search. After a lot of effort I uploaded files into my S3 bucket and I'm trying to use the search provided in the S3 bucket which says **"Type a prefix and press Enter to search. Press ESC to clear"**. I really did not find a way to search any document. Whatever I type it just says **"No keys were found for prefix search"**.

I found some answers asking to add a "/" between bucketname and filename. I did not have any luck with this, search throws me an error saying **"Prefix search does not support the character '/'. "**

I would really appreciate if someone can point out me to the right resources to learn about this or educate me on this search concept in S3 bucket.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon S3 management console does not search *inside* objects. It is purely filtering on the filename ("Key") of the objects in the bucket.

If you wish to search inside objects, then you will need to implement other services such as Kendra or Elasticsearch that will read and index objects.

Amazon S3 is a "Simple Storage Service". It provides highly scalable and reliable storage, but any higher-level functions such as search need to be implemented "on top" of S3. Just think of S3 as a huge, amazingly powerful hard disk that is connected to the Internet. (Sort of.)